# Refresh Dashboard on access

Tags: dashboard, home-page-component

I know this may sound like a strange thing, but it's there a way of refreshing a dashboard when an user access it?

We have a dashboard on our Home page and we want to refresh it for the user every time he opens the Home page. It's that even possible? To trigger an action on Home page?

PS: I'm not looking to refresh daily or once in 5 min or something like that, just on user access

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On User, access might not be possible.
Here is the link to the idea:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZGSUA3/dashboard-autorefresh